# Linked List very Strange delete

Tags: java, variables, linked-list

I have a small java application that will perform some math functions. Anyways, I have this code where I am creating points and adding them to another structure so I can use these values later. This is the code

```
/*for the sake of the example, this part is fine. these two variables are filled
 earlier but this is how they are initialized */
LinkedList<Point> col = new LinkedList<Point>();
LinkedList<Point> row = new LinkedList<Point>();
/* Issue area below */
LinkedList<Point> added = new LinkedList<Point>();
while(!col.isEmpty()){
    LinkedList<Point> tempRow = row;
    while(!tempRow.isEmpty()){
        added.add(new Point(col.getFirst().x,tempRow.getFirst().y));
        tempRow.remove();
    }
    col.remove();
}
```

when this code runs the line `tempRow.remove()`is somehow removing from the actual row as well. This makes no sense to me because I have created a local variable temp of it and call THAT instance variable. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: thank you for the tip! now can you explain why a delete to the temporary variable would delete from both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are mistaken on the effect of the following line

`LinkedList<Point> tempRow = row;`

This does not create a whole new list. This merely creates an alias for `row` which you named `tempRow`. Any modification to one will also affect the other.

What you can do instead is create a new LinkedList then add everything from row to it.

`LinkedList<Point> tempRow = new LinkedList<Point>(row);`

This way tempRow will be a new list and will contain all the points from row.

Comment: in three minutes im accepting this so hard. This is what I was worried about. Thank you for clearing it up and also providing a solution!!!

Comment: im not level enough to upvote yet! when i have enough, im comin back to upvote it lol